# Optimal way to save order of jQueryUI sortable list with Meteor

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, meteor

I need some guidance/suggestions for an optimal way to save the order of a sortable list that takes advantage of Meteor.

The following is a scaled down version of what I'm trying to do. The application is a simple todo list. The end goal for the user is to sort their list where the data is picked up from the database. As the user sorts tasks, I would like to save the order of the tasks.

I've implemented this application without Meteor using php/ajax calls using [sortable's update event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) that would delete the entry in the database and replace it with what was currently in the DOM. I'm curious to know if there are a better ways to do this taking advantage of Meteor's capabilities.

The following sample code is straight off of [a live demo](http://petahhh-todo.meteor.com/).

HTML:

```
<template name="todo_list">
    <div class="todo_list sortable">
       {{#each task}}
            <div class="task">
                <h1>{{title}}</h1>  
                {{description}} 
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

JS(Without the Meteor.isServer that simply populates the database.):

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
     //Populate the template
     Template.todo_list.task = function () {
        return Tasks.find({});
     };

     //Add sortable functionality
     Template.todo_list.rendered = function () {
        $( ".sortable" ).sortable();
        $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
     };
}
```

Sample data (Output of Tasks.find({})):

```
[{
   title:"CSC209",
   description:"Assignment 3"
 },
 {
   title:"Laundry",
   description:"Whites"
 },
 {
   title:"Clean",
   description:"Bathroom"
 }]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd probably want to first [sort your items](http://docs.meteor.com/#sortspecifiers) by a new field on you collection then, you'll want to hook into the [jQuery sortable `update` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update):

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
     // Populate the template
     Template.todo_list.task = function () {
        return Tasks.find({}, { sort: ['order'] });
     };

     // Add sortable functionality
     Template.todo_list.rendered = function () {
        $('.sortable').sortable({
            update: function (event, ui) {
                // save your new list order based on the `data-id`.
                // when you save the items, make sure it updates their
                // order based on their index in the list.
                some_magic_ordering_function()
            }
        });
        $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
     };
}
```

You template would look a bit like this:

```
<template name="todo_list">
    <div class="todo_list sortable">
       {{#each task}}
            <div class="task" data-id="{{_id}}">
                <h1>{{title}}</h1>  
                {{description}} 
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

And when that event is triggered, it would determine the order of the list and save the new `order` in the documents for the collection.

This isn't really a complete answer, but hopefully it helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you. This solution will be efficient enough for what I'm working on where the list is relatively short. I was thinking maybe a linked list may be super fast but there is no way to replicate the idea of a pointer without traversing all elements.