# jQuery UI saving sortable list to PHP array

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to save the order of a table with jQuery UI (sortable) to a PHP array.

I have simplified it very considerably but this is the basic idea of it.  I have a table with a sortable list embedded in it. The table is generated through a PHP `foreach` involving the multi-dimensional array that is included in another file (`config.php`).

`config.php`:

```
<?php
$config     = array(
    "mno" => array('item 5'),
    "abc" => array('item 1'),
    "ghi" => array('item 3'),
    "pqr" => array('item 6'),
    "jkl" => array('item 4'),
    "vwx" => array('item 8'),
    "def" => array('item 2'),
    "stu" => array('item 7'),
);
?>
```

table (`index.html`):

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" align="center" id="mytable">
    <tbody>
```

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    include 'config.php';
    foreach($config AS $name => $value){
        $item = $value[0];
        echo '
        <tr id="'.$name.'-'.$i++.'">
            <td>'.$item.'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
?>
```

```
    </tbody>
</table>
```

scripts (`index.html`):

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add jQuery UI library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
            ui.children().each(function() {
                $(this).width($(this).width());
            });
            return ui;
        };

        $("#mytable tbody").sortable({
            helper: fixHelper,
            opacity: 0.5,
            scroll: false,
            update: function () {
                var data = $('#mytable tbody').sortable('serialize');
                $.post("edit.php", {'neworder': data});
            }
        }).disableSelection();
    });
</script>
```

The sorting works fine but I don't know how to save the neworder value (`$_POST['neworder']`) into the array what is in `config.php`.

I think I must use the PHP functions `uasort()` (or `uksort()`, `uksort()`) with the combination of `file_put_contents` to save the new order in `config.php`.

So something like this:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['neworder'])) {
    /* 
    Here file_put_contents in config.php the new order. So:
    $config     = array(
        "mno" => array('item 5'),
        "abc" => array('item 1'),
        "ghi" => array('item 3'),
        "pqr" => array('item 6'),
        "jkl" => array('item 4'),
        "vwx" => array('item 8'),
        "def" => array('item 2'),
        "stu" => array('item 7'),
    );

    Becomes:
    $config     = array(
        "abc" => array('item 1'),
        "def" => array('item 2'),
        "ghi" => array('item 3'),
        "jkl" => array('item 4'),
        "mno" => array('item 5'),
        "pqr" => array('item 6'),
        "stu" => array('item 7'),
        "vwx" => array('item 8'),
    );

    After this is send by Jquery UI:
    neworder:abc[]=1&def[]=6&ghi[]=2&jkl[]=4&mno[]=0&pqr[]=3&stu[]=7&vwx[]=5

    I've tried this:
        $filename = 'config.php';

        $lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
        $linenumber = 2;
        foreach( $_POST['neworder'] AS $name => $val){
            $phost = $val[0];

            $lines[$linenumber] = ' "'.$name.'" => array(\'' . $phost . '\'),';
            $linenumber++;
        }

        file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines ) );

    But the '$val' is not send with Jquery only the order.

    */  
}
?>
```

Comment: Saving data into php files is a bad idea. You can store them in some json or xml format. If you need to do it on a larger scale/more frequently, you have to use a database.

Comment: @GerritHoekstra Hi I want to help you and think its not so hard but I want to know why you are doing it in this bad way? Can I change some part of it as it became better? I mean in general a tables with two or more columns that can be sorted with jui and as its sorts or as user clicks on a button the new order save? why you don't use JSON or XML format to save? and a file named JSON_Config_reader.php in witch reads that JSON file and make that array?

Comment: @GerritHoekstra - you know what. You could just put a comment for me saying 'nice try'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use usort with a closure (available in php 5.3+) to get the keys in the order that you need them in.

```
$newOrder = $_POST["neworder"];
$config_keys = array_keys($config);
usort($config_keys, function($a, $b) use($newOrder) {
      return array_search($a, $newOrder) - array_search($b, $newOrder);
});
```

Then you can change rewrite $config into the new order

```
$newConfig = array();

foreach($config_keys as $key){
    $newConfig[$key] = $config[$key];
}
$config = $newConfig;
unset($newConfig);
```

From here you can persist $config in whatever method makes the most sense for your use case. I would advise against using it to create a php file though, a better approach may be to use

```
file_put_contents($cacheFile, serialize($config));
```

then to retrieve

```
$config = unserialize(file_get_contents($cacheFile));
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use this. It works with this modification in jQuery UI: `update: function () {
      var a = $('#mytable tbody').sortable('toArray');
      var newOrdering = [];
      for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
         newOrdering[i] = a[i].substring(0, a[i].indexOf('-'));
      $.post("edit.php", {'neworder': newOrdering});
     }`

Answer (score 1):

There are so many threads that covers your problem

1. [jQuery UI Sortable, then write order into a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633341/jquery-ui-sortable-then-write-order-into-a-database)
2. [save jquery ui-sortable positions to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097168/save-jquery-ui-sortable-positions-to-db)
3. [Optimal way to save order of jQueryUI sortable list with Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842137/optimal-way-to-save-order-of-jqueryui-sortable-list-with-meteor)
4. http://dev.nirmalya.net/articles/javascript/saving-ordering-of-a-sortable-list-using-jquery-ui

I am sure you will find your answer there. All is about getting the order via

```
$('#mylist').sortable('toArray');
```

save it to database

and then get the order from database and show it properly with loop. Take a look at tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

`$(function() {
 $("ul.sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable',
   update: function(event, ui) {
   /* var position = $('.sortable').sortable('serialize', {
            key: 'menu',
            connected: true
        });*/
    $('div').empty().html( $('.sortable').serial() );
    }
  });
});`

Comment: (function($) {
$.fn.serial = function() {
 var array = [];
 var $elem = $(this); 
    $elem.each(function(i) {
      var menu = this.id;
        $('li', this).each(function(e) {
                array.push( menu + '['+e+']=' + this.id  );
        });
    });
    return array.join('&');      
    }
 
})(jQuery);